# how to move arrow to right on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

How can I make padding for an arrow move the arrow to right on hover?
That is, arrow moves from the text to the right, and when hover disappears, it returns to its place.

```css
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  color: #383736;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  right: 75px;
  transition:         0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition:      0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:     0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:    0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#next:before{
  content:"Next";
  position:absolute;
  color:#383736;
  right: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#next:hover:before{
  right:100%;
  transition:         0.6s ease-in;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<a  id="next"><span class="arrow">&#10230;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a translation on the arrow element (the span):

```css
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  color: #383736;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  right: 75px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#next:before {
  content:"Next";
  position:absolute;
  color:#383736;
  right: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#next:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
#next span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}
#next:hover span {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<a  id="next"><span class="arrow">&#10230;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  color: #383736;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  right: 75px;
  transition:         0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition:      0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:     0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:    0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#next:before{
  content:"Next";
  position:absolute;
  color:#383736;
  left: 50%; // <--- here
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#next:hover:before{
  left:100%; // <--- here
  transition:         0.6s ease-in;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: for what, i want  move  arrow on hover, not change position of  text

Comment: could you tell me more specifically? when mouse hover on text, then replace with arrow? let me show image as your goal.